# Minimum number of parameters to parameterize an arbitrary rotation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

The $2\times2$ rotation matrix have the form $\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$, whose each entry is a weighted sum of 2 (not algebraically independent) parameters $a$ and $b$. How does this property generalize to larger rotation matrices?

Specifically, I want to parameterize each entry in an arbitrary rotation matrix of size $n \times n$ by a weighted sum of arbitrary $m=n$ parameters. What is the minimum $m$ to guarantee to find such a parameterization?

Comment: $SO(n)$ is a Lie group of dimension $\frac12(n^2-n)$.

Comment: To the OP. You ask a very$^{10}$ bad question. That is important is the number of algebraically independent parameters. In particular, the rotations depend on ONE parameter: the angle of the rotation; the last but not the least, in some books, an angle is abstractly defined  by the matrix of the associated rotation!!

Comment: @loupblanc Right, my bad. I have edited the question to express what I actually want to know.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that $a$ and $b$ are algebraically independent? They are related by $a^2+b^2=1$.

Comment: @Rahul I see. So you mean only 1 parameter is enough to define a 2-D rotation?

Comment: @Rahul What I mean is that each entry can be computed as a weighted sum of 2 parameters $a$ and $b$. Although they can be computed from only one parameters using a more complicated computation, I am specifically interested in the case of weighted sum of parameters.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown If I'm not wrong, $\frac{1}{2}(n^2-n)$ is the rotational degrees of freedom in n-dimensional space. But how does that apply here? Can you please elaborate?